# Apache installation for django project

Tags: django, apache, configuration

Iam trying to install and configure apache for python 2.7 to develop a django application.
wsgi module is configured.
and I had did the following settings

edit httpd config file

Alias /media/ 'D:/myProjects/mysite/site_media/'

Order deny,allow
Allow from all

WSGIScriptAlias / 'D:\myProjects\mysite\apache\django.wsgi'

Order deny,allow
Allow from all

Create a folder apache in my site,say D:\myProjects\mysite\apache

Create wsgi script named 'django.wsgi'

import os
import sys
sys.path.append('D:\myProjects')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()

Create a new folder in my site folder named 'site_media'

Copy all  images,css,javascript here

Edit  template with path to css & images like this

href="/media/style.css"

[image]

But when Enter 'http://127.0.0.1' in browser  the browser is loading.....but not connecting to my site

when checked in error log

the error is

[Tue May 08 16:59:41 2012] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 1 -- Restarting.

[Tue May 08 16:59:41 2012] [warn] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.

[Tue May 08 16:59:41 2012] [warn] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.3.

[Tue May 08 16:59:41 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) mod_wsgi/3.3 Python/2.7.3 
configured -- resuming normal operations

[Tue May 08 16:59:41 2012] [notice] Server built: Sep  9 2011 10:26:10

[Tue May 08 16:59:41 2012] [notice] Parent: Created child process 2408

[Tue May 08 16:59:41 2012] [warn] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/2.7.

[Tue May 08 16:59:41 2012] [warn] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/2.7.3.

[Tue May 08 16:59:41 2012] [notice] Child 2408: Child process is running

ImportError: No module named site

Please help me ..

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496344/starting-first-django-project-errors/10497440#comment13569579_10497440)

Comment: I get it configured .Python installation was the problem

Answer (score 0):

if you are using apache2, you have to configure `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` because it doesnt use httpd.config you have mentioned...

Comment: where will be the /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default  path..please mention i searched in apache folder and i searched in drivers in system32 but i could not find

Comment: Please help me in configuring

Comment: The 000-default is there on ubuntu/debian systems, but not on all other unices (and often not on windows). And the error of the question seems to be with some path, not with the apache config file location.