# Why does Django name 2 folders the project name?

Tags: python, linux, django, mod-wsgi, wsgi

So in my Django stucture (default setup), my folder structure goes like this:

```
/mysite
    /mysite
        __init.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
    /mymodel
        ...    
    /myapp
        ...
    manage.py
```

So to access the settings file, wsgi.py is, by default, set to *mysite/settings.py*. However, Django gave the mysite name to 2 folders, one within the other. So it looks in the top level one, doesn't find it, and raises an error. I tried *mysite/mysite/settings.py* with the parent mysite's directory in the system path, but that gave the same error.

```
ImportError: Could not import settings 'mysite.mysite.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named mysite.mysite.settings
```

To get more info on this error, check [How do I stop getting ImportError: Could not import settings 'mofin.settings' when using django with wsgi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1411417/how-do-i-stop-getting-importerror-could-not-import-settings-mofin-settings-wh)

I'm just wondering why would Django make the default structure so difficult and if renaming stuff is the best way out? Seems it could be sloppy and an error-prone way of doing things. Not sure how many places I'd have to change the name if I did start renaming stuff. Seems dangerous.

Comment: You usually put the top-level mysite on your PYTHONPATH (or equivalent) so that your webserver can find mysite/settings.py.

Comment: Yep, I've done that. Maybe next I'll look into __init__.py files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The key point to understand is that the top-level `mysite` is *not* a Python package (note that there's no `__init__.py`). It's just a regular folder that's used for organizational purposes. (That's why `mysite.mysite.settings` would never work, regardless of the `PYTHONPATH`.)

All you need to do is make sure that the top-level `mysite` directory is the only thing from this project on your `PYTHONPATH`. Once you do that, everything should work the way you expect it to. (If you find the double-naming confusing, though, you certainly can, with some care, rename things.)

Comment: so basically there is no why behind all this, it's just a bad design decision?